# SQL Sum not working correctly with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I’m writing Oracle SQL for detailed and summary reports. My detailed report is finish with example output rows would be:

```
  domain name, student name, completed

  Domain Name, Student Name, Y 
  Domain Name, Student Name, N
```

Note the completed column is “Y” or “N”.

The problem is with my summary report. I’m grouping by domain name and splitting the detailed report column “Completed” of “Y” and “N” to the Summary columns of “Complete” and “Incomplete”.  I changing the “Y” to 1 or 0, and the “N” to 1 or 0 and then SUM each column.

My detailed report returns 17k rows, my Summary report returns 174 rows but total of sums are not correct. Example output for summary report is one of three types: “Domain Name, 1, 0” or “Domain Name, 1,1” or “Domain Name, 0, 0 “. These rows should have numbers like “Domain Name, 254, 110”, etc.

Any help or guidance with code would be appreciated.

```
SELECT inner_clause.dmn_id,
    SUM(decode(status_remday,'Y',1,0)) COMPLETED,
    SUM(decode(status_remday,'N',1,0)) INCOMPLETED
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT q.qual_id,
        q.qual_title,
        s.dmn_id,
        SUBSTR(pkg_student.get_delm_stud_qual_stat_rmday(sq.stud_id, sq.qual_id, sq.qual_id),1,1) AS status_remday
        FROM pa_stud_qual sq,
            pa_student s,
            pa_user_preference userPref,
            pa_qual q
        WHERE sq.stud_id = s.stud_id
            AND s.stud_id = userPref.user_id(+)
            AND userPref.user_type(+)='S'
            AND sq.qual_id = q.qual_id
            /** and q.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
            /** and s.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
            /** and s.notactive = [UserStatus] */
            /** and [security:pa_student s] */          
    ) inner_clause
GROUP BY inner_clause.dmn_id
ORDER BY inner_clause.dmn_id
```

Comment: **First** you dont need `q.qual_id,  q.qual_title`. **Second**. If your group by isnt return the result you want, check the just the inner clause the group looks ok **Last** Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: To @JuanCarlosOropeza second point. Do the results of `inner_clause` when run by itself look like what you expect? Namely, are you getting values 'Y' and 'N' out of the susbtring of that custom function? Is it giving you more than 2 or 3 results?

Comment: I removed q.qual_id and q.qual_title as suggested – thank you. I then removed the GROUP BY to check the inner SELECT. The inner_clause 
SUBSTR(package) AS status_remday did output Y and N, and the outside Select 
decode(status_remday,'Y',1,0) AS COMPLETE,
decode(status_remday,'N',1,0) AS INCOMPLETE
did output 1’s and 0’s like expected 
with results like: 
First Domain name,  Y, 1, 0
Second Domain name, N, 0, 1
The inner Select seems to be working correctly.

Comment: It’s only when I add back the GROUP BY and the SUM wrapped around the decode statements that it does not calculate correctly. I then tried changing the decode to case statements 
SUM(CASE WHEN status_remday = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "COMPLETE",
SUM(CASE WHEN status_remday = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "INCOMPLETE"

But didn't seem to have much success.

Comment: The code was retrieving the results as I requesting of it. The problem was that the inner clause needed to DISTINCT more fields for the result needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner clause needed to DISTINCT more fields for the result. The final solution was:

```
SELECT inner_clause.dmn_id,
       inner_clause.qual_title,
       SUM(decode(status_remday,'Y',1,0)) AS COMPLET,
       SUM(decode(status_remday,'N',1,0)) AS INCOMPLET,
       COUNT(decode(status_remday,'Y',1,'N',1)) AS TOTAL,
       SYSDATE AS CURRENTDATETIME
       FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT q.qual_id,
             q.qual_title,
             sq.stud_id,
             s.lname,
             s.fname,
             s.mi,
             s.dmn_id,
             sq.assgn_dte,
             sq.qual_id,
             NVL(userPref.preferred_timezone,pkg_state.get_default_timezone()) AS preferred_timezone,
             DECODE(S.NOTACTIVE,'Y','label.NotActive', 'N','label.Active') AS NOTACTIVE,
             s.email_addr,
             SUBSTR(pkg_student.get_delm_stud_qual_stat_rmday(sq.stud_id, sq.qual_id, sq.qual_id),1,1) AS status_remday
             FROM pa_stud_qual sq,
                    pa_student s,
                    pa_user_preference userPref,
                    pa_qual q
             WHERE sq.stud_id = s.stud_id
             AND s.stud_id = userPref.user_id(+)
             AND userPref.user_type(+) = 'S'
             AND sq.qual_id = q.qual_id
             /** and q.qual_id in [CurriculumSearch] */
             /** and s.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
             /** and s.notactive = [UserStatus] */
             /** and [security:pa_student s] */
             ORDER BY 1
       ) inner_clause     
GROUP BY inner_clause.dmn_id, inner_clause.qual_title
ORDER BY inner_clause.dmn_id
```